# Администирование SQL server

Tags: sql-server, администрирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, ресурсы или книги (желательно на русском), в котором бы рассказывалось про администрирование sql server. С t-sql знаком, да и по нему очень много информации в интернете, а запрос про именно администрирование (права, бэкапы, модели восстановления,блокировки, системные таблицы...) выдает только ссылки на прохождение всякого рода курсов. Спасибо!

Comment: ну не знаю, вбил запрос в гугле именно по книгам, никаких курсов он не предлагает